# Rails Does not convert unix timestamp to a datetime in params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

In my backbone app, I've decided to have my API return dates as unix timestamps (integers). When I call save on a backbone model, it will send those integers to rails, however rails seems to skip it all together, which makes sense, as it is really just an integer, so how does it know?

Is there any 'automatic' solution, where rails will recognize those as dates and make them available in my params hash accordingly? short of converting those properties manually?

I have two solutions so far:

Do it client-side, overriding the toJSON() method in a backbone model:

```
toJSON: ->
  attrs = @attributes
  attrs.start = new Date(@attributes.start)
  attrs.finish = new Date(@attributes.finish)
  _.clone( attrs )
```

I don't like this method because I lose the benefit why I switched to using timestamps in the first place: being able to use backbone's findWhere(start: timestamp). Yeah.. so, pointless.

Server-side:

```
params[:event][:start] = DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:start].to_s,'%s')
```

Or I'm crazy and should be doing it some other way? I understand Rails is meant to get along well with Backbone. I'm basically looking for an easy way to search events by date clientside.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if you have better ideas, but I'm going to mark this as answered as...

I ended up going with a simple before_filter for create and show actions on my events controller. Sometimes you want rails to do so much magic for you, it's laziness to write 2 custom lines!

```
before_filter only: [:create, :update] do
  params[:event][:start] = DateTime.strptime((params[:event][:start]/1000).to_s,'%s') if params[:event][:start].present?
  params[:event][:finish] = DateTime.strptime((params[:event][:finish]/1000).to_s,'%s') if params[:event][:start].present?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic conversion mechanism (since integers can't be assumed to be timestamps, even long ones!), but it's easy enough to do with a before_filter as you found. Additionally, it wouldn't be that hard to just wrap that up and make it a little cleaner:

```
def convert_javascript_times!(hash)
  return unless hash
  hash.each do |key, val|
    hash[key] = Time.at(val.to_i / 1000)
  end
end

before_filter only: [:create, :update] { convert_javascript_times! params[:event] }
```